# How to condition flow on number of sheets in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating a form in GAS whose responses I place in the container Spreadsheet using the `setDestination()` method. By default it is placed to be the first sheet, but I want it to be the last sheet and I also want to rename it. In order to achieve this I do these after `setDestination()`:

```
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
sheets[0].setName('new name');
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setActiveSheet(sheets[0]);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(sheets.length);
```

But there is an issue with `getSheets()`: it does not seem to detect the arrival of the new sheet in time - thus making all that follows it erroneous.

I've tried making sure `setDestination()` has finished exection before calling `getSheets()` by using callback, but that didn't help. I've also tried putting a

```
while(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().length < numOfSheetsBefore +1){
}
```

block before doing the renaming and the moving, but this just made my code run forever (also quite a mystery to me).

So, my main question is why doesn't `getSheets()` know about the new sheet that has been placed?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detail of `setDestination()`, in your situation, when `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is put after the line of `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(sheets.length + 1);`, what result will you obtain? But when this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize for this. At that time, can I ask you about the detail of `setDestination()`?

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` has solved the issue! I am grateful.

Unfortunately I don't know anything other about `setDestination()` that the reference tells (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setdestinationtype,-id).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By the way, I could understand about `setDestination()` from your replying. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

The solution as suggested by Tanaike was to call `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after `setDestination()` before proceeding to rename and move the newly placed sheet.

Comment: As a brief clarification [flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) will make sure that all the pending Spreadsheet changes are applied before moving to the next line of code as sometimes Spreadsheets keeps certain operations running in the background while moving with the rest of the script (which might cause some timing issues if you depend on these changes).